# Uninstalling freetds from OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos

Does anyone know how to uninstall `freetds` from OS X?
I have installed it from source by following instructions:

```
tar zxvf freetds-stable.tgz   
cd freetds-'0.91'   
./configure --prefix=/usr/local   
make  
sudo make install
```

`gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-include=/usr/local/include --with-freetds-lib=/usr/local/lib --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib`

My question is, what are the steps to uninstall this software?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to successfully uninstall freetds and tiny_tds gem.

first I uninstalled tiny_tds gem as below:

```
 gem uninstall tiny_tds
```

To uninstall freetds follow the instructions to configure and build the freetds before running make uninstall.(otherwise it will give this error: make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'. Stop. )

```
cd freetds-'0.91'  
./configure --preifx=/usr/local   
make
sudo make uninstall
sudo make clean
```

You will have to remove freetds.conf file manually as below:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/etc/freetds.conf
```

To ensure you have successfully uninstalled freetds run the following:

```
tsql -C
```

It should not report freetds details.

Answer (score 1):

The gem package is easy to reverse:

`gem uninstall tiny_td`

You could run `gem cleanup` to check for older versions of that package, but if you just installed it once and never updated, that isn't going to do anything further.

I've never used FreeTDS but if you're lucky this should undo what you've done : and go back to where you ran `make install` the first time then run `make uninstall` or `make -n uninstall`

If you're not lucky you'll have to do it manually (delete the files related to FreeTDS) which shouldn't be too hard, since you installed them all in to /usr/local - you could navigate there in Finder (command + G) and paste in that path).

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this. It uninstalled tiny_tds gem but not freetds.

Comment: output of the following command still reports freetds version and other details as below:

Comment: tsql –C

Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)

                            Version: freetds v0.91

             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc

     MS db-lib source compatibility: no

        Sybase binary compatibility: no

                      Thread safety: yes

                      iconv library: yes

                        TDS version: 5.0

                              iODBC: no

                           unixodbc: no

              SSPI "trusted" logins: no

                           Kerberos: no

Comment: what does `make uninstall` output ?

Comment: @maetosh, the output was :
make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'. Stop.

Comment: A gentle reminder - let's vote up hemal's question so that we all can take the discussion to chat :-)